# I need to direct modify the $sf_content what is the best workaround?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Situation: only main page is accessible by default, all other pages needs a logged in user. When a module is loaded without user, a login template should be displayed, and no module. In other words, the `$sf_content` must be emptied in `layout.php` which is not 100% ok since there is logic in the layout. Is there elegant way for that? I dont think a helper is OK either....

Comment: Can't you use setLayout ($name) in the action? Or you use forward, to change the current action to a new one.

Comment: it should be done inside filter

Comment: Inside a filter you can set the layout the following way:
     $actionStack = $this->getContext()->getActionStack();
$actionStack->getFirstEntry()->getActionInstance()->setLayout('yourLayout');

Comment: I accept it, althought the whole layout must be duplicated, but doesnt matter. Make it as post pls

Answer (score 1):

Check out security filters, this is one standard way security is designed in symfony.
You even can implement your own SecurityFilter class with the functionality you want.

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/12-Filters#chapter_12_security

Answer (score 1):

It is done by default for you by the `sfBasicSecurityFilter` filter. You just need a good configuration. Read [this part](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/13?orm=Doctrine#chapter_13_application_security) of the Jobeet tutorial. You should use `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` (or `sfGuardPlugin` if you using propell) for user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

To complete my comments above: There are different ways to override the layout. You could use the methods:

```
 setLayout($name) 
 //or using foward, which forwards current action to a new one (without browser redirection)    
 forward($module, $action);
```

inside your action class. In case you wand to modify the layout inside a filter, you can use something simular to this:

```
class yourFilter extends sfFilter {

    public function execute($filterChain) {
        if($yourConditionForOverrideTheDefaultLayout) {
            //here the syntax to change the layout from the filer   
            $actionStack = $this->getContext()->getActionStack();
            $actionStack->getFirstEntry()->getActionInstance()->setLayout('yourLayout');
        }
        $filterChain->execute();
    }
}
```

To avoid unnecessary duplication in the layout file you can work with Fragments and Partials.